# How to send Google Maps API Marker from Python server?

Tags: python, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm using Python server-side and I need to put a Google Maps Marker for every database document.
Is it possible and how?

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to handle this. I would create an API with the locations (lat, long). Then on the client side, use AJAX to consume the API and then use a loop to create new markers, appending each to the DOM. Make sense?

Comment: Yes, I think I will start on this way

Answer (score 0):

geoDjango has some good functionality for this. Create a model,set up your views, and urls.

Install django-geojson
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-geojson

Then set something up like this:

```
# urls.py
from djgeojson.views import GeoJSONLayerView
...
url(r'^data.geojson$', GeoJSONLayerView.as_view(model=MushroomSpot), name='data')
```

Then use an AJAX call to your url defined in django.